# "failed to resolve handler Apache::Registry" on Apache 2

Tags: apache-http-server, twiki

We have 2 twiki site (twiki1 and twiki2) that we use as an internal tool.
tWiki1 works, there's no problem with it. But they want me to fix the twiki2 in case twiki 1 fails.
However, I have this error in the twiki2 apache error log :

```
failed to resolve handler Apache::Registry
```

I can connect to the webserver, it asks me to auth myself, but just after it throws me a blank page, whether the auth is correct or not !

Does someone knows something about this `handler Apache::Registry error`?

I've google it and can't find nothing.

Comment: first may i know the os you have used?

Comment: It is Debian Lenny (V 5.0.9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache::Registry error is mainly occurs with the  apache server, not capable of loading the perl module.

you can fix it by adding the following line in the virtual host of your site of httpd.conf file.

```
<Location /path-for-your-cgi-bin>
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlHandler Apache::Registry
    PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
    Options +ExecCGI
</Location>
```